# Regex match at least one from set of characters in specific order

Tags: regex

I have a string which contains a sub-string of days. This sub-string contains a single character representing each applicable weekday and can contain any combination of weekdays, or the letter N where no weekday applies. Each weekday is represented by the first character, except Thursday which is an R, and weekdays must be in order.

I've tried to build a regular expression to match this substring but the regex I have written is matching blank strings.

My Regex is: `^ABC ((M?T?W?R?F?)|N) ABC$`

I want this to match:

- `ABC M ABC`
- `ABC MWR ABC`
- `ABC TRF ABC`
- `ABC N ABC`

etc...

But not match:

- `ABC Z ABC`
- `ABC TRM ABC`

The regex is doing this, but is also matching:

- `ABC  ABC`

Does anyone have a quick fix?

Edit: I forgot to mention that due to limitations of the host environment I'm restricted to using the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library and it's subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex:

```
^ABC (?=\S)(M?T?W?R?F?|N) ABC$
```

- `(?=\S)` is to make sure next character is not space.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS7xZ3/1)

Comment: The edited version with the lookahead works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be implemented as:

```
^ABC (M?T?W?R?F?|N)(?<=\S) ABC$
```